# Tableau - copy workshhet and change data source

Tags: tableau-api

I spent a lot of time on formating one worksheet in Tableau. I want to copy this worksheet and use it on other columns from the same database. Is it possible in Tableau?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on the worksheet you've prepared and choose "Copy Formatting", and you can paste it on any sheet that you create.